# FlutterFlow Custom Function return earliest date of a list of document

Tags: dart, datetime, custom-function, flutterflow

A programming question to achieve a custom function on Flutterflow.
My database is made up of a collection of users. The documents in this collection have the characteristics of the users and a sub-collection with their sports sessions. These sports sessions have a description and a date.

I would like to make a function that takes the reference of the user's document as an argument. This function must return the date of the user's next sports session (ie the closest to the current time).
Thank you very much for your help! I would very much like to understand how such a function works.

By the way, It is impossible for me to join FlutterFlow community forum. I found that a lot of people have the same problem but I don't know if this issue has been solve.

Maybe I have the idea of list of the workouts date, order them with dates and return the first one ? I've been learning python and C++ but I'm not comfortable with Dart.